# ¿ Cómo utilizar mknod desde python?

Tags: python

Estoy intentando correr este script, lo saqué de acá (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_mknod.htm)
utilizo OS: OSX EL Capitan v.10.11.2, Python: 2.7.10:

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import os
import stat

filename = '/tmp/tmpfile'
mode = 0600|stat.S_IRUSR

# filesystem node specified with different modes
os.mknod(filename, mode)
```

al correrlo en la terminal sin sudo (python testOs.py) me devuelve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testOs.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.mknod(filename, mode)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

y corriendolo con sudo (sudo python testOs.py):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testOs.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.mknod(filename, mode)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal ? Cuáles son los argumentos correctos o dónde esta el error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mi me funciona perfectamente. El script está bien.
Tendrás que buscar el error fuera del script.

He intentado reproducir tu error, pero no lo he conseguido.

Quitando permisos a /tmp:

```
test@pc:~/mknod$ sudo chmod a-wxr /tmp
test@pc:~/mknod$ python mk.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mk.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.mknod(filename, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
test@pc:~/mknod$ sudo chmod a+wxr /tmp
```

Creando antes el fichero :

```
test@pc:~/mknod$ touch /tmp/tmpfile 
test@pc:~/mknod$ python mk.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mk.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.mknod(filename, mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists
```

Por favor actualiza tu pregunta con :

- El sistema operativo que usas
- El resultado de `python --version`
- El resultado de `ls -l / | grep tmp`
- El resultado de `ls -l /tmp | grep tmpfile` antes y despues de ejecutar el script.

Yo he probado con Ubuntu 15.10 y  Python 2.7.10

**Actualizado tras la edición** :
Efectivamente, el problema está fuera del script. Al parecer esto tiene que ver con [System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html).
En [esta respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723204/956880) explican como desactivarla; pero no estoy muy seguro de que eso sea buena idea.
No tengo OSX ElCapitan y no puedo ayudarte más.

**Uso extraño de stat.S_IRUSR**
`S_IRUSR` significa que el usuario tiene permiso de lectura.
Es extraño que hagas un OR de `0600` con S_IRUSR porque `0600` ya incluye ese permiso.

Puedes comprobarlo con este código :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import stat

mode = 0600
print(mode)
mode = 0600|stat.S_IRUSR
print(mode)
```

Que en mi caso da como salida :

> 384
>   384